# Abort rethinkdb changefeed

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I'm learning RethinkDB and of course I'm interesting in using `changes()` method to get changefeed.

I know how to start them but the docs are not clear about how to stop a changefeed? Should I just call `close()` on the `cursor` passed into `run()` method or there is another way?

Comment: Which driver are you using? Usually .close() suffices => https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/close/

Comment: nodejs driver, please note you link to conn.close - I only want to stop one cursor so I think I need cursor.close() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the doc you're looking for:

https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/close-cursor/

And a quick example:

```js
let c; 

r.connect({host: "localhost", post: 28015}, (err, conn) => {
    c = conn; 
});


r.db("test").table("test").changes().run(c, (err, cursor) => {
    let cursor = cursor;
    cursor.each((item) => {
        console.log(item);
    });
});

setTimeout(() => { cursor.close() }, 5000);
```